# Pyspark - Coverting String to Array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe and it has string values where i have an array.

```
alg_mappings = {
    ('Full Cover', 40): [['base,permitted_usage'],['si_mv'],['suburb']]# Add more values as needed
}

default_value = None

def get_alg_value(sub_class, version_number):
    return alg_mappings.get((sub_class, version_number), default_value)

get_alg_value_udf = F.udf(get_alg_value)

df_with_alg = df.withColumn("alg", get_alg_value_udf(F.col("sub_class"), F.col("version")))
```

alg column is a string, but i want it to be an array element with the exact format of

```
[['base,permitted_usage'],['si_mv'],['suburb']]
```

I will be adding more elements to it, so it could even be size of 25 ++. Hence, need the most efficient way to convert it into an array. Will be adding more keys as well.

Comment: str_to_arr = udf(lambda x: [i.split(',') for i in x[2:-2].split('],[')], ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())))
df_with_alg = df.withColumn("alg_arr", str_to_arr("alg"))

Comment: Can you try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a decorator to specify the output data type on the UDF. Default is string so you get a string representation of the output.

## SOLUTIONS

Output as a list of strings

```
@udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def get_alg_value(sub_class, version_number):
    return alg_mappings.get((sub_class, version_number), default_value)
```

Output as a list of lists of strings

```
@udf(ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())))
def get_alg_value(sub_class, version_number):
    return alg_mappings.get((sub_class, version_number), default_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below approach:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
desired_format = "[['base,permitted_usage'],['si_mv'],['suburb']]"
split_elements = [x.strip()[1:-1] for x in desired_format[2:-2].split("], [")]
array_elements = [F.array(F.lit(x)) for x in split_elements]
array_column = F.array(*array_elements)
df_with_alg = df.withColumn("alg", array_column)
df_with_alg.display()
```

Results:

```
alg
[["base,permitted_usage'],['si_mv'],['suburb"]]
```

From the above code I am spliting the string into individual elements.
Converting the elements into arrays.
Then Converting the array elements into a single array column and
Converting the string column into the array column.